# ViewModel Saving Data

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, model, code-first

I have a ViewModel that contains a textbox and dropdown box and I would like to save the data to the database in MVC3.

I normally do somthing like:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    db.Orders.Add(orders);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");  
}
```

How would I do this for saving a ViewModel?

Thanks in Advance

EDIT
Ok so iv got this ViewModel:

```
namespace DropDownList.Models
{
public class CreditCardModel
{
public List<SelectListItem> CardTypeOptions { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Card Type")]
public string CardTypeID { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Card Number")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide your card number")]
public string CardNumber { get; set; }
}
}

and this controller:
namespace DropDownList.Controllers
{
public class CreditCardModelController : Controller
{
//
// GET: /CreditCardModel/
public ActionResult Index()
{
var model = new CreditCardModel();
// Populate the dropdown options
model.CardTypeOptions = GetCardTypes("MS"); // Set the default to American Express

return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(CreditCardModel model)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)

{
return RedirectToAction("addcardcomplete");
}
// TODO - Handle the form submit
// Populate the dropdown options
model.CardTypeOptions = GetCardTypes("MS"); // Set the default to American Express

return View(model);
}
// TODO - AddCardComplete goes here



// TODO - GetCardTypes goes here

private List<SelectListItem> GetCardTypes(string defaultValue)
{
List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "American Express", Value = "AE", Selected = (defaultValue == "AE") });
items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mastercard", Value = "MS", Selected = (defaultValue     == "MS") });
items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Visa", Value = "VS", Selected = (defaultValue == "VS") });
return items;
}

public ActionResult AddCardComplete()
{
return View();
}
}
}
```

How would I save this data? Once iv learnt this then I can apply it to real scenarios

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying usually you'd directly accept a model of your database object type and this time you're not?

Comment: @ AFinkelston what im doing is following this tutorial http://codeoverload.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/dropdown-lists-in-mvc-3/ but I dont know how to save the seleced values as its using a ViewModel which I have never used before as I am new to MVC3.

Answer (score 2):

Create an instance of your Entity Model and set the values of that which you are reading from the ViewModel which is posted to the action method and use that for saving to your database. Some thing like this.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveOrder(OrderViewModel orderVM)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    YourDomainEntity objDomainModel=new YourDomainEntity();
    objDomainModel.ItemId=orderVm.ItemId;
    objDomainModel.Quantity=orderVM.Quantity;
    //Set Other relevant properties also

    db.Orders.Add(orders);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index"); 

  } 
}
```

You may consider libraries like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) for Mapping from your Domain Object to Your ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean editing? You can re-attach it as modified and re-save it..

```
db.Orders.Attach(orders, true);
db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(orders, EntityState.Modified);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Though I would **strongly** advise that you break apart database objects and viewmodels. You can also use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to make life easier with regards to going back and forth, but keeps database and front-end separated.